# How to create user with Ansible correctly?

Tags: linux, ansible

I use this task to create new users on Linux

```
- name: Add user
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    group: "{{ item.group }}"
    groups: sshgroup
    append: yes
  with_items: "{{ users }}"

- name: Add .ssh directory
  file:
    path: "/home/{{ item.name }}/.ssh"
    state: directory
    mode: 0700
    owner: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ item.group }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"

- name: Add key
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/home/{{ item.name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    state: present
    create: yes
    line: "{{ item.auth_key }}"
    owner: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ item.group }}"
    mode: 0600
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Mostly the user can login via ssh successfully. But there was a case the new created user can't login with his/her private ssh key. They got a password request.

The users on the Linux like

```
$ ls -la /home/

# Can't login with ssh
drwxrwxr-x.  3 user1      user1     103 October 12 10:10 user1

# Can login with ssh
drwxr-xr-x.  7 user2      user2    4002 October 23 11:20 user2
drwx------.  3 user3      user3      80 October 21 12:00 user3
```

It seems they have different permissions. Why this caused?
If change `user1`'s permission, how to do with ansible?

Comment: Regarding the headline "_How to create user with Ansible correctly?_" it seems you are using the correct way already. To debug your specific issue with few user IDs it would be necessary to have more information about the content of `{{ users }}`, `{{ item.uid }}`, `ls -aln /home`, group membership etc.

Comment: @U880D I added two more tasks to the question.

Comment: @Miantian possibly the user existed before the provisioning via Ansible or added a password to their account? This is more a matter of the configuration of your SSH agent on the node rather than an Ansible issue. 
Worth reading: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019999/key-based-ssh-login-that-requires-both-key-and-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there alternate portions of the playbook or other users making modifications? Whether using ansible or any other method, users are typically created with a home directory permissions see to "drwx------." unless the folder already existed when creating the user or permissions were otherwise specified. If you want to ensure that it is always correct, you can always use an additional play like the following

```
- file:
    path: /home/{{ item.name }}/
    state: directory
    mode: 0700
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the ansible module one should use to create users is: **user**.
You can issue a command: `ansible-doc user` or `ansible-doc -s user` to get info about syntax to apply in your ansible playbook.
Below I would propose a playbook which is to create several (in this case two) users as well as modify /etc/sudoers if it is needed.

PS. You need to provide hashed password in the playbook to be able to log in to the created account.

```
---
- name: create user
  hosts: your_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: create users 
      user:
        name: "{{ item.user }}"
        password: "{{ item.password }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
          - { user: BBB, password: here_hashed_password }
          - { user: CCC, password: here_hashed_password }    

    - name: add sudo entry
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sudoers 
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
      with_items:
          - { line: 'BBB ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' }
          - { line: 'CCC ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' }
```